Completing Ethernaut without testnet Eth?
Is there a way to do the ethernaut challenges locally? I don't have enough testnet Eth to do the challenges. Thanks!

You can do them locally for practice and understanding, but they can't be approved or marked as completed unless you perform the required steps on-chain and submit the same.
You can let me if you want to do the challenges on Amoy Testnet, I can send you some test MATIC/POL.
